# ModX Revolution MIGX/GetImageList not displaying entire list

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have a site that was built and handed over to me, so I'm not as familiar with ModX as I'd like to be. That said, I've built my own templates, tpls and the like.

However, and existing MIGX using template is giving me fits. It used to display all the items in the list properly - one image, and three text fields. Now, it randomly will stop displaying one item.

When I say random, I don't mean that it switches around when you refresh the page - I mean right now item #4 isn't being displayed (even in source code, nothing appears). But if I were to delete any other item, that #4 might just show up again, and a different item start disappearing.

I'm at a loss here. I see no special characters in the text fields. Even if there were, that wouldn't explain how an item will work then not work then work again based on making changes to other items.

Please let me know what other information I can provide to assist in troubleshooting this.

Below is all the relevant code I can think of.

Template:

```
<div id="content">   
        [[!getImageList? 
        &tvname=`management` 
        &docid=`[[*id]]` 
        &tpl=`management_tpl` 
        &limit=`0`
    ]]
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
```

management_tpl:

```
    <div class="management_box">
  <div class="management_img">
    <img  src="[[+image:phpthumbof=`w=100&z=1`]]" alt="[[+pagetitle]]" />
  </div>
    <div class="management_content">
      <h2>[[+name]]</h2>
      <h3>[[+position]]</h3>
      [[+descr]]
      <a href="#[[+name:stripString=` `]]" class="show_more">Show more</a>
    </div>
    <div id="[[+name:stripString=` `]]" class="fulldescr">
    <img  src="[[+image:phpthumbof=`w=100&z=1`]]" alt="[[+pagetitle]]" />
    <h2>[[+name]]</h2>
    <h3>[[+position]]</h3>
    [[+fulldescr]]
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this in the future - my MIGX plugin was outdated and had some flaws that caused this. Updating the plugin fixed everything.